# Neo4j equivalent of a sql cross join

Tags: neo4j, cross-join

I have returned a list of 1000 nodes in neo4j. I want to cross this list with itself so that I can create relationships between all pairwise combinations. In sql I would simply use a cross join. Is there an equivalent function/process that would allow me to do the same in neo4j.

My first approach was to do the following:

```
MATCH (b:BASKET)
WITH count(b) AS GlobalBasketCount
MATCH (n:PRODUCT)-[:COLLECTIONS]-(b:BASKET)
WITH n,count(b) AS nBasketCount,GlobalBasketCount
WHERE nBasketCount > 0.001*GlobalBasketCount 

MATCH (m:PRODUCT)-[:COLLECTIONS]-(b:BASKET)
WITH m,count(b) AS mBasketCount,n,nBasketCount,GlobalBasketCount
WHERE mBasketCount > 0.001*GlobalBasketCount AND m.id < n.id

CREATE (m)-[r:RELATIONSHIP]->(n)
WITH m,n,r,nBasketCount,mBasketCount
SET r.BasketCountProduct = nBasketCount*mBasketCount
```

However, this requires the same product list to be created 1001 times via match queries, which is very inefficient.

Side Note: The

```
m.id < n.id
```

is to prevent duplicate pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
MATCH (n:Foo)
WITH collect(n) as nodes
UNWIND nodes as n1
UNWIND nodes as n2
WITH n1,n2
WHERE id(n1) < id(n2)
...
```

Comment: That's on the right path (excuse the pun), thanks. However, in my particular query there is a number associated with each node, 'nBasketCount'. I want the association of these numbers to their respective nodes to survive the collecting and unwinding process. I have tried that out now, but the closest I have come to doing this is collecting the pairs as arrays, but then unwind doesn't like returning the arrays. The error I get is:

"Expected `n1` to be a node or relationship, but it was `` "

Is there a way to preserve the association?

Comment: It turns out that the unwinding of the arrays is legit, and that it was the WHERE clause that was the problem. It was being applied to the unwound arrays, but obviously there is not an order on a set of arrays, in neo4j at least. I'm still investigating the unwinding of these resultant arrays and will add a comment if and when I find out how to do so, for completeness.

Comment: Ok, the 'UNWINDING' of these resultant arrays is done very easily. So I have the n1 and n2 lists of arrays, then I simply index the elements of these arrays in my RETURN clause:

RETURN n1[0],n1[1],n2[0],n2[1]